# JMeter - MongoDB Connection Error - jmeter.JMeter: Uncaught exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions

Tags: mongodb, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using MongoDB_Source_Config and MongoDB_Source to connect to my Mongo DB as shown in images below - [image]

[image]

but on running this I am getting following error -

```
jmeter.JMeter: Uncaught exception:  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions$Builder.autoConnectRetry(Z)Lcom/mongodb/MongoClientOptions$Builder;
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.config.MongoSourceElement.testStarted(MongoSourceElement.java:139)
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:214)
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:336)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you change the mongodb driver jar ?

Because this issue means there is a different version of driver than the one embedded in JMeter.

Show versions of mongodb drivers

Comment: -  I am using jmeter 2.11 and mongo-java-driver-3.0.2.jar

Comment: Yes ... it was version issue, downgraded my mongodriver. It's working fine now. Thanks a ton.

Comment: I would be very interested to know how you use MongoDB sampler ? In the JMeter team we intend to drop it as we didn't have much feedback on it.

Comment: I am creating some accounts and later-on deleting those accounts from mongo db

Comment: I am using  jmeter 2.11 r1554548   that is already available in software repo. of my company. They might have changed some jars etc.