# How to fetch mongo db data and pass in jmeter request

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I have one post call that response is like this.

```
{
  "status":0,
  "message":"Prescription Created",
  "jsonResponse":{},
  "cid":"C5975K",
  "pid":"Rx5975K-175A",
  "prescriptionSource":"GO_RX_CTO",
  "imageStatus":[]
}
```

By taking this pid , I have to do the query for the one more record. For example:

```
db.order.find({"pid":"Rx5975K-175A"})
```

and the result of this query should pass in one more jmeter request.

I have used MongoDB Script (DEPRECATED) .. But this wont work as its deprecated ..

Tried with JSR223 Sampler, but its not working in new jmeter 3.2

```
import com.mongodb.*
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject

    MongoCredential coreCredential = MongoCredential.createCredential("${mongodb_user}", "${mongodb_database}", "${mongodb_password}".toCharArray());
    MongoClient coreMongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("${mongodb_server}", 13017), Arrays.asList(coreCredential));
    DB coreDB = coreMongoClient.getDB("${mongodb_database}");
    DBCollection coll = coreDB.getCollection("order");
    coll.find();
```

Comment: what's the error? did you add mongodb jars?

Comment: i have mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar ..  When i m using mongo db scripts.. below is the error. 12:15:03,093 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions$Builder.autoConnectRetry(Z)Lcom/mongodb/MongoClientOptions$Builder;
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.config.MongoSourceElement.testStarted(MongoSourceElement.java:140) ~[ApacheJMeter_mongodb.jar:3.2 r1790748]
 at

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JMeter - MongoDB Connection Error - jmeter.JMeter: Uncaught exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38890365/jmeter-mongodb-connection-error-jmeter-jmeter-uncaught-exception-java-lang)

Comment: I already seen above stack flow question.. I have tried with down grading mongo db driver and mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar also , bson-3.4.2.jar..  But its not working.. I have jmeter : 3.2 ..

Answer (score 0):

You have to find your result based on "pid" and you are nowhere passing it. After finding you collection you need to create a query and searching using that query.

import com.mongodb.*
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject

```
MongoCredential coreCredential = MongoCredential.createCredential("${mongodb_user}", "${mongodb_database}", "${mongodb_password}".toCharArray());
MongoClient coreMongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("${mongodb_server}", 13017), Arrays.asList(coreCredential));
DB coreDB = coreMongoClient.getDB("${mongodb_database}");
DBCollection coll = coreDB.getCollection("order");
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("pid", "Rx5975K-175A");
DBObject  getData= coll.findOne(query);
```

and this will give you the desire result